# How to terminate early a functional computation

Tags: performance-tuning, functional-style

**Problem description**: Given a list $A=\{1,2,0,7,0,-1,2,6,\ldots\}$ and a list $B=\{0,7,0\}$ write a program that determines whether $B$ appears in $A$ or not. Note: the order of $B$'s items *does* matter.

**Functional way**:

```
MemberQ[Partition[A, 3, 1], B]
```

The disadvantage of this way is that the whole list $A$ is processed even if $B$ is in the very start of $A$. Compare with the following code which terminates early if $B$ is found in $A$:

**Procedural way**:

```
found = False;
L = Length@A;
For[i = 1, i <= (L - 2) && !found, i++,
found = Take[A, {i, i + 2}] == B]
```

**Question**: Is there a *functional* way of solving the problem that does  not need to scan/process all of $A$'s elements ?

P.S. Feel free to edit the title.

Comment: Not very efficient `a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b = {2, 3, 4};
MatchQ[a, {___, PatternSequence @@ b, ___}]` A Boyer-Moore type alg should be better

Comment: @belisariushassettled. On cursory reading about Boyer-Moore, it says that there is pre-processing done on the list in order to reduce the number of comparisons done. OP doesn't seem to want pre-processing (though your observation might mean that the OP *should* want pre-processing instead!).

Comment: @march Boyer-Moore preprocesses the **needle** (i.e., $B$), not the **haystack** ($A$).

Comment: @Pillsy. That's why one shouldn't post comments after a "cursory reading".

Comment: @march I was looking for a good example http://stackoverflow.com/a/6209778/353410

Comment: @belisariushassettled. That is an excellent explanation! I should have trusted that you'd read the post carefully.

Comment: @march Don't trust too much :)

Comment: Your functional method is much faster than your procedural one, especially if the sequence you are looking for isn't in a long list.

Answer (score 10):

More recent (10.1+) versions of Mathematica feature the [`SequencePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html) function, which can be told to stop after the first match, like so:

```
SeedRandom[1337];
a = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10000];
b = {1, 7, 1};

SequencePosition[a, b, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.000175, {{88, 90}}} *)
```

This is quite a bit faster than the `MemberQ`/`Partition`-based approach:

```
MemberQ[Partition[a, 3, 1], b, {1}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.00199, True} *)
```

As a word of warning, you can use more general patterns with `SequencePosition` and similar functions, but as of version 10.3 the performance is only really good with fixed patterns like `{1, 7, 1}`.

**EDIT** to add: It seems to provide a similar speedup over other solutions, like in @belisarius' comment:

```
MatchQ[a, {___, PatternSequence @@ b, ___}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.019747, True} *)
```

Comment: I'm on V9- Could you please compare this with my cheap solution on the comments? I guess this one is faster, but I'm curious about the improvement

Comment: @belisariushassettled on my OS X box with 10.3 this method was `Timing` 0.000548 whereas the `MatchQ` timing was 0.027489

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks a lot!

Comment: and the `NestWhile` methods were 0.019667 with the same `a` and `b` lists

Comment: you seem to be only seeing a bit over an order of magnitude enhancement whereas on my computer after clearing cache etc. I am seeing two orders of magnitude (??)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Doing `ClearSystemCache` first slowed down the `MatchQ` a lot; updated to reflect.

Comment: Timing depends, of course, on where in `a` the first instance of `b` occurs, and selecting the same `RandomSeed` seems not to guarantee the same position across operating systems.